# How to convert TDM csv file into Term Docment Matrix by tm package in R?

Tags: r, document, tm

I have term document matrix in csv file. For example,

```
       , doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5
main   ,    2,    0,    3,    0,    0

virtual,    4,    0,    0,    0,    1

origin ,    0,    0,    1,    2,    0
```

....

How can I convert this to term document matrix in tm package?

I think the term document matrix by `TermDocumentMatrix()` function can be created from the sentences (list of words) in documents.

But I already have term document matrix and I would like to import and use it in tm package.

Please let me know the method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach (but there's likely a direct way within the `tm` package):

```
x <- read.csv(text="   , doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5
main , 2, 0, 3, 0, 0

virtual, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1

origin , 0, 0, 1, 2, 0", header=TRUE)


library(qdap)
dat <- x[, -1]
row.names(dat) <- x[, 1]
your_tdm <- tdm(as.wfm(dat))

tm::inspect(your_tdm)

## > tm::inspect(your_tdm)
## A term-document matrix (3 terms, 5 documents)
## 
## Non-/sparse entries: 6/9
## Sparsity           : 60%
## Maximal term length: 7 
## Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
## 
##          Docs
## Terms     doc1 doc2 doc3 doc4 doc5
##   main       2    0    3    0    0
##   origin     0    0    1    2    0
##   virtual    4    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Thanks. Tyler Rinker. I tried to your suggestion, but I got some errors. When I installed "qdqp" packages, it could not find some zip files. I found it is because of the version problems. So I manually download new version of files and installed. However, when I tried call libray(qdqp), it shows "package 'qdap' was built under R version 3.0.3, package 'qdapDictionaries' was built under R version 3.0.3.

Comment: Also, when I tried "your_tdm <- tdm(as.wfm(dat))", R shows "Warning in as.wfm(dat) : Not a matrix.object; may not convert correctly". My R version is 3.0.3 and this may make a problem. I don't know how I can solve it. I sincerely appreciate to your help.

Comment: The first issue is because you're using an old version of R.  The second thing is a warning, not an error.  The bottom line is, does it work?

Comment: Dear Tyler. I solved problems. I sicerely thanks for your helps

Comment: @user3436056 If this works you may want to consider checking the checkmark to green indicating this was the best solution.